# Android - GridView with different item height

Tags: android, gridview

Please excuse my bad English, I'm French !

I've got a question for my Android App...
I have to display 3 row of pictures with differents height.

But I can't find a way to do that properly...
I think use three synchronised listview is very durty...

Do you know how could I do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Staggered Grid View](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/).

Comment: Good ! It work fine but.... There is not onScrollListener !! How can I do when I want to detect the end of the list ?